# Writing about website component in active voice

Tags: active-voice

I can't seem to figure out how the below sentence would be written in a passive voice, even though my spelling software is complaining about it. Is there a way to rewrite it that I'm not seeing?

"*The full-text search field is used a few times per day.*"

It's specifically highlighting "*is used*" as the error which seems essential in any sentence structure to me...

Comment: It is not an error. There are cases where passive voice should probably be avoided, but not here. Your sentence with active voice would read like this: "(Someone/something) uses the full-text search field a few times per day," i.e. you need a subject that acts upon the object (full-text search field), but it's really not necessary.

Comment: @Wehage: why don't you make that a proper answer, so we can up-vote it?

Comment: @virolino Point taken. It was originally just going to be "it's not an error," but off I went.

Comment: It's not clear to me if the sentence means something like "a normal user uses it a few times per day" or "all users together only use it a few times per day." Using active voice is one way to clarify. A better way might be to add "across all users" to your passive construction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not an error. There are cases where passive voice should probably be avoided, but not here. Your sentence with active voice would read like this:

> (Someone/something) uses the full-text search field a few times per day.

I.e. you need a subject that acts upon the object (full-text search field), but it's really not necessary.

A few examples [here](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/academic_writing/active_and_passive_voice/choosing_passive_voice.html) of when it is appropriate to use the passive voice.

Comment: And worse, 'Someone uses the full-text search field a few times per day' could misleadingly suggest that it's the *same* someone each time!